NodeMailer Gmail/Outlook authentication issue despite correct credentials
I'm encountering an authentication issue when trying to send emails using NodeMailer with Gmail or Outlook. Despite providing the correct credentials, I'm receiving the following error:
{
  "code": "EAUTH",
  "response": "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. For more information, go to\n535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials lr16-20020a056a00739000b006e319d8c752sm13343092pfb.150 - gsmtp",
  "responseCode": 535,
  "command": "AUTH PLAIN"
}

I'm unable to enable two-factor authentication (2FA) because the email account doesn't belong to me. Is there a workaround for this issue, or are there alternative email services compatible with NodeMailer that I could use?
Here's the NodeMailer code I'm using:
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: process.env.USER,
    pass: process.env.APP_PASSWORD,
  },
});

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
